# Script to parse fields, changing format of the nth

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to take the contents of a pipe-delimited text file with a bunch of fields. Field 10 is a timestamp, and it either has the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, or `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS`. If it's the former, I want to append a `.'000'` to the end of that field - otherwise I want to leave it alone, and I want to leave the other fields unchanged.

I'm trying to do it currently with `awk`. It seems to be working, but my solution feels a bit *awk* ward :-)

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
{for(i=1;i<9;i++) printf "%s|",$i; printf "%s|",$9}
{printf($10 ~ /\./) ? substr($10,1,10)" "substr($10,12)"|" : substr($10,1,10)" "substr($10,12,18)".000|"}
{for(i=11;i<NF;i++) printf "%s|",$i; printf "%s\n",$NF}'
```

Anything I can do to tidy things up a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to golf this to a "one-liner". Actually, you only need a rule that modifies field 10 if it encounters a timestamp without milliseconds, and one rule that simply "prints" the entire line for the general case (including the possible modification due to rule 1). So, assuming `GNU Awk`:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$10 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){2} ([[:digit:]]{2}:){2}[[:digit:]]{2}$/ {$10=$10".000"} {print}' textfile
```

should do the trick.

The above RegExp is for most cases overly "thorough" in checking the timestamp. If you trust your file format enough, you can reduce the check of field 10 to

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$10 ~ /:[0-5][0-9]$/ {$10=$10".000"} {print}'
```

which also doesn't require the GNU version of `awk` anymore.

Applying this to a test input

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|i|j|k|2020-01-20 10:22:33|m|n|o
a|b|c|d|e|f|i|j|k|2020-01-20 10:22:33.123|m|n|o
```

yields:

```
~$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$10 ~ /:[0-5][0-9]$/ {$10=$10".000"} {print}' testinput

a|b|c|d|e|f|i|j|k|2020-01-20 10:22:33.000|m|n|o
a|b|c|d|e|f|i|j|k|2020-01-20 10:22:33.123|m|n|o
```

Answer (score 0):

Just alter the 10th field.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
     NF>9 && $10 !~ /\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ {  $10 = $10".000" }
     {print}'
```

You can replace `{print}` with `1` for a shorter solution, the newlines within the single quotes are optional.